# What can I use that is small, has linux, an ethernet port, and a hard drive?

Tags: linux, hardware

I see that David Braben has created a $25 USB stick that can run linux. Check out the website at http://www.raspberrypi.org/

[raspberry-pi-stock-pcb-480.jpg http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2531/raspberrypistockpcb480.jpg](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/2531/raspberrypistockpcb480.jpg)

That's not available yet - so what's a low power *nix device that I can connect to a network and also an ethernet port? Doesn't have to be secure or anything. Preferably something without a fan would also be nice

Comment: that device is meant to be out in about 6 weeks i think. May be worth waiting.

Comment: I hope it becomes available soon. However I'm always a little skeptical of timelines promised for technology products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the various ARM-based plug computers will serve you well. They also come in larger (i.e. OMAP-based) forms if you need more horsepower.

For example: GuruPlug, PogoPlug, TonidoPlug, BeagleBoard, PandaBoard.

Comment: do you have any links to these?

Comment: GuruPlug, PogoPlug, TonidoPlug, BeagleBoard, PandaBoard.

Answer (score 2):

Also see these:

Plugcomputer.org- http://www.plugcomputer.org/development-kits/

Tonidoplug - http://www.tonidoplug.com/

PWN Plug 3G - http://www.pwnieexpress.com/3gplug.html

Ionics - http://www.ionics-ems.com/plugcomputer.html

Many Sheeva and a few GUI Plug computers - http://www.newit.co.uk/shop/products.php?cat=5

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) project - which ports Linux onto SoHo [routers](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices).

Not gone through the complete hardware list, but, e.g. a linksys wrt45GL costs about 45 UKP retail (less vat, converting to $...approx 58 USD). You might want to dig further to find a device which might support USB / memory cards.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it fits your definition of small, but I have been using boxes based on the ALIX board for linux-based firewalls.  I use the [ALIX.2D13 appliance](http://store.netgate.com/Netgate-m1n1wall-2D3-2D13-Blue-P217C83.aspx) it is x86-based, has USB ports, and a PCMCIA slot, and the 100MB network interfaces, comes with a 2GB CF card.

You can't boot off the USB ports, but you can certainly attach a couple USB hard disk, if it has separate power.  The board provides minimal power to the USB ports.

Answer (score -2):

You can get used eeepc very cheap, $100, and it has HDD, display, keyboard, ethernet and wifi.

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what he means by "small"